# Cutting a rectangle into four equal triangles from a corner in rectangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

If a rectangle $ABCD$ is cut into four triangles of equal area by lines $AF$, $AG$ and $FG$,where point $F$ is on $BC$ and $G$ is on $CD$, what is $BF$ and $DG$ interms of $BC$ and $CD$ respectively?

Comment: Quite obviously, $BF={1\over2}BC$ and $DG={1\over2}CD$. Also, welcome to Math.SE.

Answer (score 1):

This is a trick question.

In order for $\Delta ABF$ to have $\frac14$ of the area of the rectangle, we need $F$ to be the midpoint of $BC$.
Likewise, we need $G$ to be the midpoint of $CD$.
But then $\Delta FCG$ has only $\frac18$ of the area of the rectangle!